# Can't connect to Vagrant public network

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, mamp, vagrantfile

I've recently switched from MAMP to Vagrant (using VirtualBox). With MAMP any computer connected to my WiFi network would have access to a project by simply entering the host IP into it's web browser. With Vagrant however, I can only connect to the VM from the computer that's running it.

Changing `config.vm.network "private_network"` to `config.vm.network "public_network"` isn't working for me. In fact, even though the VM will launch and allow me to SSH, I can no longer access it from my browser.

**Vagrantfile:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
end
```

I've tried both setting and not setting the IP address, and use `en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)` for the bridged network interface.

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible with Vagrant?

Comment: Can you access the web server on <hostip>:8080?

Comment: @beel nope. The loading icon spins for a second, but ultimately it fails. :/ I'm wondering if it's something to do with how my internet is setup — although I think it's a pretty standard.

Comment: What you have for a `Vagrantfile` looks correct to me.  Can you provide the output from `vagrant up`?  And what is the host os?

Comment: @Beel I got it working! But I can't specify a hostname or my own IP — I have to let it assign one for me and manually add the a host name to my /etc/hosts/ file.

Answer (score 8):

I've been able to fix this issue by assigning a static IP to my Vagrant VM that is in the same local range as my host machine.

For example:

My Host machine is: `192.168.1.123`

This will work:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.201"
```

But this will NOT:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.201"
```

Comment: Extremely helpful!

Comment: This was the exact issue with my configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remember to do a `vagrant destroy` as sometimes certain changes are not made until the box is recreated from scratch.